# Automatically protecting Sheets after saving

Tags: excel, vba, password-protection

[image]

I am trying to automatically lock cells after user has hit save button. The sheets is protected and contains some unlocked cells where user can input data.

Now I want those cells to get locked after user has clicked data. I have multiple sheets in the workbook but I want this to happen just for the first sheet.

```vb
Option Explicit

Dim Ws As Worksheet
    
Private bRangeEdited As Boolean
'Private WithEvents Ws As Worksheet
    
    
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set Ws = Range("A1:ZZ27").Parent
End Sub
    
    
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim sMSG As String
    sMSG = "Beim Speichern der Arbeitsmappe werden die Eingabezellen gesperrt. " & vbLf
    sMSG = sMSG & "Möchten Sie fortfahren ?"
    If Not bRangeEdited Then GoTo Xit
    If Not Me.ReadOnly Then
        With Range("A1:ZZ27")
            If MsgBox(sMSG, vbExclamation + vbYesNo) = vbNo Then
                Cancel = True
                GoTo Xit
            End If
            Unpro_SheeTS
            '            .Parent.Unprotect "1234"
            If .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Address <> .Address Then
                .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Locked = True
                bRangeEdited = False
            End If
            Pro_SheeTS
            '            .Parent.Protect "1234"
        End With
    End If
Xit:
End Sub
    
Private Sub ws_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    If Not Intersect(Range("A1:ZZ27"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        bRangeEdited = True
    End
End Sub
    
Sub Unpro_SheeTS()
    
    For Each Ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        Ws.Unprotect ("1234")
    Next
    Exit Sub
    
End Sub

Sub Pro_SheeTS()
     
    For Each Ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        Ws.Protect ("1234")
    Next
    Exit Sub
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey i have changed the code ,however the entered cell doesn't get locked and also I believe that my Main sub doesn't get run. Something to do with Range and parent property.
I have 10 to 15 sheets and inside i HAVE CELLS which are unlocked. Those cells needs to get locked after I have entered data in it and clicked save button.
Thank you once again

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you should have a worksheet_change event function which keeps track of what cell is modified in a list/array/collection as you feel.
On the other hand your Workbook_BeforeSave event would go through the sheets you want and for each of them it would unprotect the sheet, lock the cells (worksheet.range(...).locked = true) then protects the sheet.
(You dont need to protect the workbook for your purpose, it is a different matter)

for you to have better results :

- indent your code
- refer to ranges from a worksheet explicitly
  (worksheet.range)
- consider migrating to another language ;)

Comment: hey thanks ,
However I have multiple sheets and I want it to work for every sheets and not just 1 particular sheets.

Comment: Then all these sheets shall have the worksheet_change. Since your Workbook_BeforeSave event would go through the sheets you want and for each of them it would unprotect the sheet, lock the cells and then protect the sheet.